# Is there a way to express factorial-like matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have a number of $N \times N$ matrices of real numbers, $A_1, A_2, \cdots, A_K$. Is there a way to mathematically express

$A_K! = A_K A_{K-1} A_{K-2} \cdots A_2 A_1$?

I know $A_K!$ is not standard notation, but is there way to express factorial-like matrix multiplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\Pi_{i=1}^k A_i
$$
is pretty standard. This just doesn't come up enough to deserve its own one-character special symbol, esp. because you'd need to know what sequence it was being applied to. In the naturals, for instance, "!" is used for a product of sequential positive values, but "!!" for a product of all even (or all odd) sequential values.